# Getting a error "variable 'cmd' is used before its assigned a value"

Tags: vb.net

I found the Code that follows online, which will help a lot with a project i am working on, if anyone can recommend a fix it would really be appreciated:

```
    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        'open connection if it is not yet open
        cnn.Open()
    End If
```

The below line is one with the error, variable 'cmd' is used before its assigned a value:

```
    cmd.Connection = cnn
    'check whether add new or update
    If Me.tbMemNo.Tag & "" = "" Then
        'add new
        'add data to table
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO athlete(memno, firstname, lastname, dob, gender, joindate, memfeeout) " &
                      " VALUES(" & tbMemNo.Text & ",'" & tbFirstName.Text & "','" & tbLastName.Text & "','
                      " & dpDOB.Text & "','" & cboGender.Text & "','" & dpClubJoinDate.Text & "','
                      " & tbMemFeeOut.Text & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Else
        'update data in table
        cmd.CommandText = "Update athlete " &
                        " SET memno = " & tbMemNo.Text &
                        ", firstname = '" & tbFirstName.Text & "'" &
                        ", lastname = '" & tbLastName.Text & "'" &
                        ", dob = '" & dpDOB.Text & "'" &
                        ", gender = '" & cboGender.Text & "'" &
                        ", joindate = '" & dpClubJoinDate.Text & "'" &
                        ", memfeeout = '" & tbMemFeeOut.Text & "'" &
                        " WHERE memno = " & tbMemNo.Tag
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
    'Refresh data in list
    RefreshData()

    'clear form
    btnClear.PerformClick()

    'close connection
    cnn.Close()
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Try this: `Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = cnn.CreateCommand()`

Comment: Thanks so much! Dim cmd As new OleDb.OleDbCommand worked

Comment: Never ever concat values into a string to make a query.  It is a disaster waiting to happen as well as the root cause of many other problems including syntax errors and data type mismatches